# How to test a button inside a Material UI Select using React-Testing-Library

Tags: jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I have a button named "Open dialog" inside Material-UI Select. If I click on it, a dialog will open. I need to write test cases for that button which is inside Select. Can someone explain me how to do it. I am using snapshot testing and this is the code. The test case is failing as "**unable to find data-testid openDialog**"

main code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from '@mui/material/Select';
import { Button, Dialog, DialogActions, Typography } from '@mui/material';

export default function BasicSelect() {
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState('');

  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
    setAge(event.target.value as string);
  };

  const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = React.useState(false)

  return (
    <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
     <FormControl fullWidth>
      <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
       <Select
        labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
        id="demo-simple-select"
        value={age}
        label="Age"
        onChange={handleChange}
        inputProps={{'data-testid': 'selectForm'}}
        >
        <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        <div style={{bottom: 0}}>
          <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => setOpenDialog(true)} data-testid="openDialog">open dialog</Button>
        </div>
      </Select>
     </FormControl>

    <Dialog open={openDialog} maxWidth={'sm'}>
    <Typography>hii all</Typography>

    <DialogActions>
      <Button onClick={() => setOpenDialog(false)} data-testid="cancel">Cancel</Button>
    </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
    </Box>
   );
   }
```

This is my test code:

```
import { render, fireEvent, screen, cleanup, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
```

and the test case is

```
    it('Open dialog', async() =>
{
    const { container } = render(
        <ThemeProvider>
                <Demo />
        </ThemeProvider>
    );

    const selectForm = screen.getByTestId('selectForm')
    fireEvent.click(selectForm);

    const openDialog = await waitFor(() => screen.getByTestId('openDialog'));
    fireEvent.click(openDialog);

    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't have a good answer for you, but if you don't have the Testing Playground browser extension, you could check it out. It should help you find good ways to identify elements on your screen, and will also give some recommmendations if there are better ways to do it. It doesn't always work though, for some reason. Maybe it's because I use a different browser than the one it's made for.

Comment: did you find an answer? have the same issue

Comment: No @Nikita, not for the above code.  I've replaced Button with another MenuItem and added some styles to it. I have given some "value" to the MenuItem and moved the click functionality into onChange function. In the unit testing, I've used fireEvent.change to test it.